# UFW on debian vps not working as expected

Tags: linux, firewall, ufw

I have a Debian 11 VPS server with ufw installed and running with some rules working and others don't, I have tried resetting, disabling, reloading and even uninstalling but all in vain.
Here is my verbose status

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5000:5300/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5000:5300/udp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5000:5300/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5000:5300/udp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

With the following response from `sudo ufw show listening`

```
tcp:
  110 * (dovecot)
  143 * (dovecot)
  22 * (sshd)
   [ 1] allow OpenSSH

  25 * (master)
  443 * (nginx)
   [ 2] allow 'Nginx Full'

  465 * (master)
  5001 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5002 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5003 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5004 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5005 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5006 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5007 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5008 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5009 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5010 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5011 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5012 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5013 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5014 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5015 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5016 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5017 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5018 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5019 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5020 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5022 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5023 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5024 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5025 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5026 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5027 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5028 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5029 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5030 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5031 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5032 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5033 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5034 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5035 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5036 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5037 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5039 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5040 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5041 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5042 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5043 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5044 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5045 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5046 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5047 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5048 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5049 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5050 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5051 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5052 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5054 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5055 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5056 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5057 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5058 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5059 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5060 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5061 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5062 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5063 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5064 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5065 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5066 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5067 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5068 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5069 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5070 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5071 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5072 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5073 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5074 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5075 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5076 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5077 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5078 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5079 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5080 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5081 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5083 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5085 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5086 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5087 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5088 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5089 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5090 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5091 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5092 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5093 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5094 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5095 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5096 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5097 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5098 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5099 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5100 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5101 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5102 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5103 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5105 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5106 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5107 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5108 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5109 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5110 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5111 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5112 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5113 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5114 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5115 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5116 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5117 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5118 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5119 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5120 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5122 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5123 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5124 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5126 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5127 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5128 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5129 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5130 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5131 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5132 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5133 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5134 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5135 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5136 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5137 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5139 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5140 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5141 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5142 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5143 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5144 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5145 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5146 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5147 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5148 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5149 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5150 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5151 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5152 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5153 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5154 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5155 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5156 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5157 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5159 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5160 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5161 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5162 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5163 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5164 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5165 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5166 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5167 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5168 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5169 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5171 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5172 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5173 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5174 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5175 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5176 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5177 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5178 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5179 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5180 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5181 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5182 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5184 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5185 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5186 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5187 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5188 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5191 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5192 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5193 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5194 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5195 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5197 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5199 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5200 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5201 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5202 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5203 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5204 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5205 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5206 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5207 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5208 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5209 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5210 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5211 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5212 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5213 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5214 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5215 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5216 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5217 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5218 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5219 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5220 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5221 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5222 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5223 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5225 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5226 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5228 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5229 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5231 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5232 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5233 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5234 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5235 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5236 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5237 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5238 * (java)
   [ 3] allow 5000:5300/tcp

  5355 * (systemd-resolved)
  587 * (master)
  80 * (nginx)
   [ 2] allow 'Nginx Full'

  8082 * (java)
  993 * (dovecot)
  995 * (dovecot)
tcp6:
  110 * (dovecot)
  143 * (dovecot)
  22 * (sshd)
   [ 7] allow OpenSSH

  25 * (master)
  443 * (nginx)
   [ 8] allow 'Nginx Full'

  465 * (master)
  5355 * (systemd-resolved)
  587 * (master)
  80 * (nginx)
   [ 8] allow 'Nginx Full'

  993 * (dovecot)
  995 * (dovecot)
udp:
  5001 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5002 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5003 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5004 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5005 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5008 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5009 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5013 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5016 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5018 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5020 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5021 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5027 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5031 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5032 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5033 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5038 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5039 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5044 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5051 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5052 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5053 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5064 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5074 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5078 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5081 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5082 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5084 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5086 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5103 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5104 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5121 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5125 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5134 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5138 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5145 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5147 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5158 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5170 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5183 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5189 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5190 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5191 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5196 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5198 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5207 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5224 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5227 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5230 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5236 * (java)
   [ 4] allow 5000:5300/udp

  5355 * (systemd-resolved)
udp6:
  5355 * (systemd-resolved)
```

Any Help is really appreciated thanks alot.

Comment: "running with some rules working and others don't" won't help readers guess what is your problem, even less solve it. Your question isn't clear. You should [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1104858/edit) it to add some clarification. What should be working and isn't working? How are you testing it doesn't work? Does it work when the firewall is disabled? etc.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by reviewing my system setup and found out that I am using IRedMail which automatically sets up `nftables` also Debian's default. So All I had to do was to configure nftables to my will by adding my rules to nftables instead of iptables/ufw.